# Accessing values of unknown Dictionary Keys

Tags: objective-c, ios, json, nsarray, nsdictionary

My JSON response looks like this:

```
    {
    "themes": [
        [
            "Direction des Routes Secteur de Pithiviers ",
            "mairies",
            "Morailles 45300 PITHIVIERS LE VIEIL ",
            "0238345744",
            "48.823042",
            "2.365907"
        ],
        [
            "Crédit Mutuel Du Centre ",
            "banques",
            "agence de Pithiviers  33 r Am Gourdon 45300 PITHIVIERS",
            "0820834080",
            "48.703042",
            "2.145907"
        ]
    ]
}
```

As you can see, all the Keys are unknown, i don't have `Key:value`, so, how can i refer to each value.

```
NSDictionary *allThemesDict=[[request responseString]JSONValue];
 NSArray *allThemesValues=[allThemesDict objectForKey:@"themes"];
    for (int i=0; i<[allThemesValues count]; i++) {
        NSDictionary *currentTheme=[allThemesValues objectAtIndex:i];//here i get the first 6 values, how can i display it?
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're arrays, not dictionaries. So you can just grab the array like this:

```
NSDictionary *allThemesDict = [[request responseString] JSONValue];
NSArray *allThemesValues = [allThemesDict objectForKey:@"themes"];
for (int i=0; i<[allThemesValues count]; i++) {
    NSArray *currentTheme = [allThemesValues objectAtIndex:i];
    NSLog(@"currentTheme = %@", currentTheme);

    // Then access [currentTheme objectAtIndex:1] for example to get "mairies" in the first case.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's only one key in your example: the top-level dictionary has a key called "themes". Everything else is an array or a primitive.

On the assumption that you don't know in advance the "themes" key will be called "themes", you can discover it by iterating over the dictionary. You may encounter a problem in that if you don't know what the keys are, you may not know enough about the data to predict the type and content of the value. The solution here is to agree with the server developers a specification for the data format. For reference, you iterate over a dictionary like this (there's more than one way):

```
for (id key in myDictionary) {
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you simply want to iterate through the array? In that case, something like this could work:

```
    NSDictionary *currentTheme=[allThemesValues objectAtIndex:i];
        for (id item in currentTheme) {
            NSLog(@"item: %@", item);
        }
    }
```